# multiple views want single search field is it possible in drupal?

Tags: views

I have developed Multiple views with multiple nodes.like(View1 , View2,View 3).

- In these three views Name field is same.
- so is that based on Name filed search feature is possible or not.
- I have tried with views default search criteria,but its working for only particular views only.

any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a single exposed filter for multiple views. 
There is a workaround though:

- Make a new view that displays the three types of nodes you declared before.
- Make sure you use "display: content" in your view
- Choose a view mode
- Expose the name field that is used on the different content types

So it all comes down to using 1 view

Comment: I am not understood what you are saying..can youplz elaborate your answer.

Comment: Hi..i have tried your approach..and its working,but it is not working as my requirement.I want only search field in new created view(i.e block).when i am search that title then that time it display.